# How to get ACPI health data on a Gigabyte GA-890GPA-UD3H?

Tags: acpi, sensors

I have a Gigabyte GA-890GPA-UD3H motherboard and Phenom II X6 in my desktop computer, and it's all working well, except that Ubuntu 10.10 doesn't seem to detect any ACPI support at all: it can't suspend, and it can't measure its internal temperatures.  I would have thought a new device like this ought to have pretty pervasive ACPI support?

Comment: I'd still like to get suspend/resume working, but I guess that's totally separate from thermal monitoring?

Comment: You are right! But what happens when you suspend? Do you have error message?

Comment: Suspend problems often connected to video cards and depends on drivers (especially proprietary ATI drivers)

Comment: I'll file a separate question for the suspend/resume thing, with more details.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: [question 12558](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12558/usb-blocks-suspend-on-a-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h-with-ati-sb700-sb800) has more information about suspend/resume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For temperatures, you must install **lm-sensors** package

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Then follow this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it - I had installed lm-sensors but I hadn't run `sensors-detect`.