# USB blocks suspend on a Gigabyte GA-890GPA-UD3H with ATI SB700/SB800

Tags: usb, suspend, power-management

Following on from [question 12397](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12397/how-to-get-acpi-working-on-a-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h), I'd still like to get suspend working on my Phenom II X6 / GA-890GPA desktop machine running current Maverick.

When I run `pmi action suspend` the machine doesn't crash, but it also doesn't suspend.  The kernel logs show:

```
PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.02 seconds) done.
Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
PM: Entering mem sleep
Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
pm_op(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -2
PM: Device usb8 failed to suspend async: error -2
PM: Some devices failed to suspend
PM: resume of devices complete after 0.430 msecs
PM: resume devices took 0.000 seconds
PM: Finishing wakeup.
Restarting tasks ... done.
PM: Syncing filesystems ...
```

I've tried disconnecting all the USB devices, and then connecting in to run `pmi` over ssh, and I get the same failure.  With everything unplugged, I see the following usb devices:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and lspci shows the physical devices are:

```
00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.5 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI Controller
02:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

Booting with `no_console_suspend` makes no difference.

Comment: Hm, but what is usb8 and what is ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 ?

Comment: I think it's the [south bridge of the AMD 700 series motherboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_700_chipset_series#SB700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a USB3-compatible motherboard?

If so, check this: [Computer won't sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17077/computer-wont-sleep)

I had the same problem (although my device ID was 'usb12', the message was otherwise identical). The fix detailed in the above link worked like a charm and fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, I do!  Thanks very much, that looks like it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try different kernels from kernel PPA, you may be lucky. Try 2.6.32, 2.6.35, 2.6.36 final versions (without rc), and 2.6.37.rc1 too.
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Install only linux-image-x.x.x-generic_...(i386 or amd64).deb