# Computer won't sleep

Tags: 10.10, suspend, troubleshooting, suspend-resume

When I try to put my Ubuntu 10.10 box to sleep or into hibernation, it appears to wake up right away (couple of seconds at most). I am trying to figure out what's going on, and would appreciate any suggestions.

`syslog` says:

```
Dec 12 13:15:25 mig kernel: [13049.728355] pm_op(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -2
Dec 12 13:15:25 mig kernel: [13049.728357] PM: Device usb3 failed to suspend async: error -2
Dec 12 13:15:25 mig kernel: [13049.728451] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
```

Now, how do I find out which device is `usb3` and why it's failing to suspend?

The only external USB device in the system is a dongle for wireless keyboard and mouse. If I disconnect it, ssh into the box and run `pm-suspend`, it still fails with exactly the same error message.

`lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so the setup isn't exactly extravagant. The mobo is Asus P7P55D-E based on the P55 Express chipset.

**edit** It turns out `usb3` wasn't the name of a *device* but was a reference to the USB 3.0 *protocol*. If I disable the latter in the BIOS, the box can sleep!

*This is cross-posted from superuser.com, since there are no answers there and the question is Ubuntu-specific.*

Comment: Have you checked dmesg and the syslog?

Comment: Is there anything specific I should be looking for? I did have a look everywhere I thought relevant, but couldn't find any clues.

Comment: @karthick87 I just found something in `syslog` which (inexplicably!) I was overlooking before. I'll update the question.

Comment: Might be better to answer your own question and close it properly?

Comment: My keyboard was plugged in to the usb3 port. I plugged it into the usb2 port and the problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

do you say that you have a motherboard that support usb 3.0 well that a well know issue that happened when the box is in suspend mode,

When the XHCI module is loaded for USB 3.0 operation the system cannot suspend. Manually unloading XHCI will allow suspend to complete normally. To avoid future suspend problems, the workaround is to add SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci-hcd" to /etc/pm/config.d/unload_module then the system can suspend normally.

P7P55D-E

```
* Intel LGA1156 Platform / Intel® P55 Express Chipset
* **True USB 3.0** or SATA 6Gb/s Support - Future Transfer Technology
* ASUS Hybrid Technology
* ASUS 16 Hybrid Phase Design*
  *16 Hybrid Phase = 12+2 Phase x T.Probe
* TurboV EVO - Ultimate O.C. Processor
* T.Probe - Leading Active Cooling Technology
```

Description of the bug and How to Fix : [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998)

Comment: (+1) Thanks, I've found the Launchpad report as soon as I've figured out that `usb3` in the logs wasn't referring to a device, but rather to the protocol.